# SimpleDB as backup?

Tags: backup, rdbms, nosql, amazon-simpledb

Is there any solution (RDBMS or NoSQL) that can use SimpleDB as a backup?

Thanks,
  A.

Comment: You should be more specific about the problem you're trying to solve. On the surface I would say using SimpleDB as a backup for an RDBMS makes no sense. You don't typically copy data from one type of structured repository into another of a different type unless you're performing a one-shot data conversion or replication between a legacy system and its (phased-in) replacement.

Comment: What I'm looking for is using SimpleDB as a 'transaction log', so a database (RDBMS or not never mind) can ensure that even if the server goes down, there is a fast and reliable way to extract all the data from SimpleDB and build it up again. So I'm not looking for some external backup solution to S3, I'm looking for an integrated backup that can be used to re-build the database if required.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure no RDBMS can be configured to do this, and I doubt they ever will. First, SimpleDb is a quasi-competitor to commercial databases so it wouldn't make sense for most companies to build this. Second, it would have a huge negative effect on transaction performance since writing transactions to SimpleDB would probably take at least 100 times as long as writing them to disk.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I thought, because of the performance you have mentioned, the competition is not so direct and the other features of SimpleDB (data redundancy) will make it as compelling central backup solution (at least we have such a business need).

Comment: Its a backup, and SimpleDB has no locks I don't see a transaction hit, just add them to the todo list, you can throw multiple threads at it, recording transactions with an ID. Storage is cheap, too.